# how to create document term frequency matrix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

To create a document term matrix I have text file `result.txt` as input. I am trying to count the words occurrence in this manner:

```
Counter({'STTP': 6, 'AVENUES': 4, 'ENGINEERING': 4, 'MINING': 4, 'THE': 4, 'SCOE': 4, 'HERE': 4, 'DATA': 4, 'TOOLS': 4, 'PROGRAMMING': 3, 'TEMPERATURE': 3})
```

But got the result in this manner:

```
"degree,the,mituski,programming,national,it,high,sakal,engineering,paper,college,signed
1,4,2,3,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,1"
```

Here is the code I used:

```
tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()

files = glob.glob("result.txt")

for f in files:

    content = open(f).read()

    content = content.replace('\n', ' \n')

    tdm.add_doc(content)

    tdm.write_csv('matrix1.csv', cutoff=1)
```

Comment: The code didn't show the use of `Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a correctly formated `csv` file. The first row is the header (words) and the second row is the count of the words.

The thing you are showing looks like a `dict` passed to a `class` constructor.

From [Python Textmining Package](http://www.christianpeccei.com/textmining/index.html):

> ## Instead of writing out the matrix you can also access its rows directly.
>
> ```
> # Let's print them to the screen.
> for row in tdm.rows(cutoff=1):
>     print row
> ```

So for getting a `dict` as in your question you can go by:

```
result_rows = list(tdm.rows(cutoff=1))
result_dict = {}

for i in range(len(result_rows[0])):
    result_dict[result_rows[0][i]] = result_rows[1][i]
```

Comment: got this error:  for i in range(len(result_rows[0])):
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'                                       i want output in csv file

Comment: You're csv file is actually a valid csv. The example you show in Counter looks like a dict. I updated my answer and fixed the bug, as I didn't know that tdm.rows is a generator, not a list.

Comment: btwy i hav one more question : how can i apply above output(Document term frequency matrix) as input to LDA algorithm??

Comment: You can have a look at the package `gensim` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim) which can do a LDA. However, you have to check what input is needed an adjust your data accordingly.